# Me gustaria saber porque no me funcionan funciones como como el .strip y el .append

Tags: python

[image: Se ve como Visual studio code no me reconoce .append ni .strip con unos ejemplos]

El problema que tengo es que no puedo utilizar ninguna de estas funciones de python, he estado buscando pero no he visto a nadie que tenga mi problema, seguramente sea una tonteria, pero me estoy iniciando en esto de la programacion y la verdad no tengo ni idea
de como resolverlo, no se si es problema de visual studio code o es mio, he estado buscando pero he seguido sin encontrar el problema

Comment: Bienvenido. El código va como texto.

Comment: Lecturas sugeridas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola estimado Gatero06.

En la primera parte de tu código estas definiendo una **TUPLA** la cual tiene los siguientes métodos o funciones:

- `.count()`
- `.index()`

Si lo que en realidad quieres en una **LISTA** y emplear el método `append` debes modificar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
lista1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
lista1.append("e")
```

---

En la segunda parte de tu código intentas utilizar el método `strip` en una TUPLA y esta no posee este método;

`strip` es un método empleado para elimina los espacios al principio y al final de la CADENA de texto:

Ejemplo:

```
texto = "    ejemplo    "
texto = texto.strip()
```

Tienes que leer la documentación referente a los tipos de datos y los métodos que estos poseen. [Tipos de datos python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp)
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ambas variables contienen [tuplas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples).

Las tuplas no tienen ninguna función `strip` ni `append`.

Las tuplas son un tipo de dato **inmutable**, lo que significa que no pueden ser modificadas. Por lo que no tampoco tendría sentido que defina una función `append`.

---

Quizá hayas querido usar una [lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists), que sí es mutable y por ende define una función [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable).

Pero las listas tampoco tienen la función `strip`. Puedes ver [en la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=strip) qué tipos cuentan con una función llamada así.

Las cadenas de texto son unos de ellos. Lo que hace es remover una serie de caracteres del comienzo y el final de la cadena.

Ejemplo de la documentación:

```
>>> '   spacious   '.strip()
'spacious'
```